# Is it possible to store a data from recyclerview by using only SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I'm new in android and also new in English sorry my bad English...

I have learned  android course at the academy. The last class was SharedPreferences. So teacher gived a task that use SharedPreferences at the app which we make during the course.

The app contains a recyclerview, it is made up text and check box and button.

So I think SharedPreferences is only deal with String, int, boolean and also long like primitive .... and also recyclerview is made up item with position.

So I found the way to store, before go to the class, list of text of recyclerview by using GSON. But teacher said we do not use GSON...

So ask youguys Is it possible to store a data from recyclerview by using only SharedPreferences??? If it is not possible.

How to commonly store the data of recyclerview??

Comment: Please add the datatype of the Recycler.Adapter

Comment: Share your code and layout.

Comment: okay!! plz wait

Comment: targetInfo class is missing

Comment: oh sorry T^T I edit agian

Comment: See https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#5 and https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to commonly store the data of recyclerview??

That is generally done by using a **database**. On mobile it is SQLite. You can read about it here: [Save data using SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite). SQLite is now easier to use with [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), which is built over SQLite. Related video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKWh4ckvFPM).

> list of text of recyclerview by using GSON. But teacher said we do not
>   use GSON...
>   Is it possible to store a data from recyclerview by using only
>   SharedPreferences?

Yes, it possible to store data from recyclerview. You do not need GSON.

You have used **targetlist** ArrayList to store data from RecyclerView. Just add a method **toString** to turn it into a string. In this method loop over your list and concatenate them to a string which you can write to SharedPreferences as a string. To get the items back, just fetch back the string (also known as [CSV or Comma Separated Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) and perform [.split()](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/java-split-csv-string-to-list/) on it.

Example List data:

1. Cat
2. Bat
3. Rat

Concatenated String: Cat,Bat,Rat (Save this Concatenated String with commas to Shared Preferences).

Some example code:

```
//Concatenating List Data and position   
String string_item_name_to_save = targetlist.get(0);
String string_item_position_to_save = "0";    
for(int i = 1; i<targetlist.size(); i++){
    string_item_name_to_save = string_item_name_to_save +","+ targetlist.get(i);
    string_item_position_to_save = string_item_position_to_save +","+ Integer.toString(i)
}

//Convert comma separated String back to List
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(concatenated_string.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Comment: Um... It is hard to understand..... If it is not burdon to you. could you give me a more information for Example??? I don't understand that if i make a lot of targetlist, how the data concatenates targetlist with itemlist ...

Comment: Ah sorry my bad...I've not renamed the variable correctly, I'll edit it.

Comment: T^T     I confuse. String type only have one imformation. Even though I use 'for' method the you inform, eventually the 'string_to save' save the last number of targetlist.get(last number) For example the targetlist contain 2 word like targetlist.add(0,"a") ,  targetlist.add(2,"b"). The 'string_to_save' save "a,b". But when I retrieve, I need also '0' position of targetlist..

Comment: You want to save the positions of items in array? You can do those too by adding it to another string called positions or to the same string. I'll update the answer.

Comment: You do not need to keep the positions in any separate string. The index of your items List after getting data back from your concatenated_string will be the position of your data in the recycler. But, you can keep an additional string with positions if you want.

Comment: Um.. you mean after save the date to items and then put the code ? like......SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREEFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString(Item);

Comment: Follow this link and learn the usage of Shared Preferences.  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

After you've understood how to add string to shared preferences, and getting them back. You can then add the concatenated strings as required.

Comment: Um.. I know the baisc SharedPreferences method.. SharedPreFerences need Key and Valus to save the data.. and it is like hash table way. I think that sharedPreferences needs as value count as key count...  I think that List<String> litems =Arrays.asList(concatenated_string.split("\\s*,\\s*"));  is valuse. so how could i get key?? This is my confusing point.

Comment: Put any string as key. For example: "recycleview-items" or "recycleview-positions". Another tutorial here: https://www.coders-hub.com/2013/10/how-to-use-shared-preferences-in-android.html#.XIVM1CIza01

Comment: Um??? just one "key" can save a List?? lie editor.putStrng("recycleview-items", items) ??

Comment: Oh I understand. I'm gonna try this again.!!! Thank you for your generosity !! Thanks  alot!!

Comment: Wait, sorry. That key is like a variable name to that data. You will be fetching back the concatenated_string from shared preferences that you saved earlier in string_item_name_to_save.